# Is the Query Correct I am not gettting results after inserting data in sqlite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Not getting Data in the resultset

Here's the code

```java
public boolean isExist(String question_id, String selected_option, String session_id) {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEST_START + " WHERE question_id_test_start = '" +question_id+  "' AND selected_option_test_start = '"+selected_option+"' AND test_start_id = '"+session_id+"'", null);
        boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
        Log.d("DATA PRESENT ","DATA CHECK"+exist);
        cur.close();
        db.close();
        return exist;

    }
```

Comment: DATA CHECK is always coming false

Comment: Though i inserted data and in log cat it is showing data inserted

Comment: Now when i am checking data is present or not it is Showing DATA CHECK FALSE

Comment: You are comparing your ids to **strings**. But normally, ids are **integers**, therefore it won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code, hope so it will solve your p.

```
 public Cursor isExist(String question_id,String selected_option,String session_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                    TABLE_TEST_START + " WHERE " +
                    question_id_test_start + "=? AND " +
                    selected_option_test_start + "=? AND " +
                    test_start_id + "=? ",
            new String[] {question_id,selected_option,session_id}
    );
}
```

After getting the Cursor value you can check whether it exists or not